# What is "Terminating in response to backboardd's termination"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, crash-log

i use a piece of code for drop shadow on a view with help of slider. Slider is set -15 to 15. This code works awesome when `slider.value` is positive but app stop working if its negative.
the crash log is weird `Terminating in response to backboardd's termination`.

i got this log first time.**What is that?**

here is my code.

```
    childViews.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    childViews.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(slide,slide);
    childViews.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    childViews.layer.shadowRadius=10;
    childViews.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    childViews.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Comment: I am getting this exact error when I enable accessibility inspector on the simulator. not sure if it is related.

Comment: I am also getting this error in my iOS 7.1 simulator. Not sure how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check your app if its using too much memory instantly. Sometimes instant memory leads to backboard daemon's termination. As apple said to me. :-) This might be your app or your mac machine.

Answer (score 2):

backboardd is the companion daemon for SpringBoard. "Terminating in response to backboardd's termination” most likely means that backboardd crashed. Check to see if there are any backboardd crash logs and, if present, file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: @John, did u mean that it is an apple bug? But for me this issue is happening while executing a specific feature of the App.

Comment: Yes, I did mean that it's an Apple bug. There should be nothing that your app can do to cause backboardd to crash.

Comment: @arango_86 Just check your app if its using too much memory instantly. Sometimes instant memory leads to backboard deamon's termination. As apple said to me. :-)
This might be your app or your mac machine.